# Overall system IR: How to do arithmetic with $\delta$ functions?

Tags: convolution, impulse-response

When finding the overall system impulse,

how to do arithmetic with $\delta$ functions?

E.g.
\begin{align}
h[n]&=h_1[n]\star h_2[n]\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_1[k]h_2[n-k]\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \left(2\delta[k-2]-3\delta[k+1])(\delta[n-k-1]+2 \delta[n-k+2]\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (2\delta[k-2]\delta[n-k-1]+2\delta[k-2]2 \delta[n-k+2]-3\delta[k+1]\delta[n-k-1]-3\delta[k+1]2 \delta[n-k+2])
\end{align}

The two middle terms are convolutions. But what about the two other? What to do with them?

Or am I supposed to leave the indices there, rather than evaluating the $\delta$ functions?

Comment: you are sure they are **multiplied** and not **convolved**, right ?

Comment: Here it's multiplication, not convolution. But the above expression was found through convolution of the signals in $()()$.

Comment: You shall better formulate the convolution first, it seems there is an unconventional use of the variables n and k.

Comment: That seems to be the convolution between two sums of two deltas. What about doing the operation in the Fourier domain, and then coming back?

Comment: @Tendero I haven't been taught Fourier transforms yet.

Comment: have you learnd the **graphical** method? (also called as the flip and drag method) which is extremely useful and helpful in the **intuitive** evaluation of convolution sums. Also note that your **dummy** index of integration is **n** , which generally by convention is **k**, that's to say: $y[n] = x[n] \star h[n] = \sum_k h[k]x[n-k] = \sum_k h[n-k]x[k]$. Please reformat your question accordingly.

Comment: Good. Now eventhough I would **highly** suggest you to use the **graphical** method, in which you would sketch h1[k] as a function of **k** and h2[n-k] as flipped wrt **k** and shifted according to **n**, you can instead follow the tabulated summation form, by first applying the **sifting** property I have described in my answer and then evaluating the resulting deltas for each **n**, so that you can evaluate $h[n]$ for each n.

Answer (score 2):

You make it unnecessarily complicated.

Given 
$$\begin{align}
h_1[n]&=2\delta[n-2]-3\delta[n+1]\\
h_2[n]&=\delta[n-1]+2 \delta[n+2]
\end{align}$$
to calculate
$$h[n]=h_1[n]\star h_2[n]$$

the easiest way is to use the sampling property of delta, which is

> $$f[n]\star\delta(n\pm n_0)=f[n\pm n_0]$$

So you can write as follows

$$\begin{align}
h_1[n]\star h_2[n] &= h_1[n]\star \left(\delta[n-1]+2 \delta[n+2]\right)\\
&=\color{green}{h_1[n-1]}+2\color{blue}{h_1[n+2]}\\
&=\color{green}{2\delta[(n-1)-2]-3\delta[(n-1)+1]}+2\color{blue}{\left(2\delta[(n+2)-2]-3\delta[(n+2)+1]\right)}\\
&=2\delta[n-3]-3\delta[n]+4\delta[n]-6\delta[n+3]
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the **sifting** property,
$$
 x[n] \delta[n-m] = x[m]\delta[n-m]
$$

specifically applied when $x[n]$ is $\delta[n-k]$ where $k$ is an integer,
$$
 \delta[n-k] \delta[n-m] = \delta[m-k]\delta[n-m]
$$

which is equivalent to $\delta[n-m]$ when $k=m$ and otherwise identically $0$, when $m \neq k$ .

You can apply the result term by term. Give it a try and tell us your result.

Hint: (from your post)
$$h_1[n] = 2\delta[n-2] - 3\delta[n+1]$$
$$h_2[n] = \delta[n-1] + 2\delta[n+2]$$
$$h[n]=(h_1[n]*h_2[n])$$

I suggest you at this point (for these very short impulse responses)
to use the **distribution** property of convolution and the convolution property of the $\delta[n]$.

i.e. 
$$ (x_1[n] + x_2[n]) \star h[n] = x_1[n] \star h[n] + x_2[n] \star h[n] $$

Comment: I don't see how the distribution property applies here. Or does $\delta$ also have convolution property?

Comment: if you look at my last line, you can see the distrbution of convolution over addition there. Then you shall replace $x_1[n]$, $x_2[n]$ and $h[n]$ with appropriate signals. Then you will apply convolution property of impulse to obtain the final result.